# Akka how to connect source, flow, and sink

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I have created a source, flow and a sink

The source is an integer source

The flow transfers the integer to string

and the sink writes to a file

But I don't know how to connect all of them together to get a runnable graph

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
        Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);
        Source<Integer, NotUsed> source = Source.range(0, 100);
        Flow<Integer, ByteString, NotUsed> flow = Flow.fromFunction((i) -> {
            return ByteString.fromString(i.toString());
        });
        Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<IOResult>> sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("love.txt"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I focus your wording "runnable graph".
Please look at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html#constructing-graphs with care of taking java for your programming language at the left side for the correct code samples.
On this page is a runnable graph sample code, which should help you to connect your streaming elements together.

Comment: I think the https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-quickstart.html is a a better place to start out when learning the flow based API from scratch.